# "UnicodeDecodeError : 'ascii' codec can't decode byte" when handling Chinese language command line arguments with ElementTree

Tags: python, utf-8, encode, elementtree, python-2.x

I have an XML file `test.xml`, with content:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Configurations version="1.0">
    <Item name="a" value="avalue" />
    <Item name="b" value="bvalue" />
</Configurations>
```

And I want to change some attribute values with Python ElementTree.
The python program is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#coding=utf-8
###############################################################################
import sys
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

a_value = ""
b_value = ""
# Functions to modify the Upgrader configuration files.
def Modify_Config ():
    tree = ET.parse('./test.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()
    for child in root.getiterator():
        childName = child.get('name')
        if 'a' == childName:
            child.set('value', a_value)
        elif 'b' == childName:
            child.set('value', b_value)

tree.write('./test.xml', encoding="UTF-8")
###############################################################################
a_value = sys.argv[1]       
b_value = sys.argv[2]
###############################################################################    
Modify_Config()
```

when I execute the python file like this: "encode.py 测试 bvalue" in Windows Command Prompt, it ends with exception:

```
D:\Test_study\python\encode>encode.py 测试 bvalue
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Test_study\python\encode\encode.py", line 25, in <module>
    Modify_Config()
File "D:\Test_study\python\encode\encode.py", line 20, in Modify_Config
    tree.write('./test.xml', encoding="UTF-8")
File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 821, in write
    serialize(write, self._root, encoding, qnames, namespaces)
File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 940, in _serialize_xml
   _serialize_xml(write, e, encoding, qnames, None)
File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 933, in _serialize_xml
   v = _escape_attrib(v, encoding)
File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1091, in _escape_attrib
   return text.encode(encoding, "xmlcharrefreplace")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb2 in position 0: ordinal
not in range(128)
```

Why does that error occur? My OS is windows 7, 64 bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

byte strings and unicode strings are exchangeable only when there are only characters < 128. The elements sys.argv contents are byte strings in python 2.x. Furthermore, it seems that they are encoded in GB2312, not UTF-8. Thus you need to be explicit:

```
a_value = sys.argv[1].decode('GB2312')
b_value = sys.argv[2].decode('GB2312')
```

Comment: Thanks.The argv's encoding is GB2312.But the code "a_value = sys.argv[1].decode('GB2312')" has error in my Windows Command Prompt,the error is " Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Test_study\python\encode\encode.py", line 22, in <module>
    a_value = sys.argv[1].decode('UTF-8')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 3: invalid s
tart byte", Sorry for the tanglesome error information.